# WPF DataGrid: header misaligned and unnecessary scrollbar

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I'm using the WPF `DataGrid` to display some data. The definition is the following:

```
<Grid>    
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGridArchivio" 
          Grid.Row="1" Margin="3"
          CanUserAddRows="True" 
          CanUserDeleteRows="False" 
          IsReadOnly="False" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          RowEditEnding="dataGridArchivio_RowEditEnding">
    <!-- Column definitions, irrelevant to our problem -->
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

The result I get is the following:

[image]

The problems are highlighted in the screenshot. To reiterate:

1. When the control first appears, the column header is misaligned with the cells. As you can see, it is missing that little gray triangle that rows have, which causes the bad alignment
2. There is an unnecessary horizontal `Scrollbar`. The `DataGrid` is inside a `Grid` and thus it should automatically resize.

The funny thing is: **as soon as I either resize the window or move the horizontal Scrollbar everything gets fixed: the header re-align correctly and the Scrollbar disappears!**

So, how can I fix this so that it looks correctly right from the start, without having to manually move the Scrollbar or resize the window?

Comment: could you write all xaml. I mean where do you put your DataGrid(Grid, StackPanel or ScrollBar)?

Comment: Have you tried `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"`?

Comment: @CBreeze: unfortunately doesn't work. But I found the solution in the meantime, check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found a solution:

```
<DataGrid RowHeaderWidth="0" ... />
```

This removes those gray boxes on the left, fixes the alignment and makes the `ScrollBar` disappear.